# Multiple SQL queries containing every element in a Python list in the LIKE operator

Tags: python, sql, list, iteration

I am trying to run multiple `SQL queries` where the `LIKE` operator contains every element of a list in **Python**.  I have a long list of strings

```
l = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3',....]

query_1 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[0]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[0])
query_2 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[1]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[1])
query_3 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[2]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[1])
```

and so on.

How would I run multiple queries and then concatenate them? Is it possible to use the `execute` function on multiple queries or can it only work with one? Would I use a for loop?

EDIT: In the previous version of this question, I asked about running **ONE** query with multiple list elements in the `LIKE` operator. I realized that the final query was something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[0]' OR LIKE 'l[1]' OR LIKE 'l[2]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'.
```

That was not what I needed.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: why do u want to run the commands simultaneously? have u tried `executescript` method for the cursor?

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, I edited the question so that I want to run multiple queries and then concatenate the results into one list.

Comment: just run the query and append the result to list

Comment: yes it is python, it is line by line interpretter u jus have to run the code and then append both the results. But should u be using formatted strings or place holders?

Comment: Why can't you just write the queries as unions?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not looking for parallel execution just do the below (**pseudocode**)

```
l = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3',....]

query_1 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[0]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[0])
query_2 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[1]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[1])
query_3 = "SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE 'l[2]' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'".format(l[1])
result = [] 
query_lst = [query_1 ,query_2 ,query_3]
for query in query_lst:
   temp = query.execute()
   result.append(temp)
```

If you are interested in parallel execution - see this example

https://pythonprogramming.net/values-from-multiprocessing-intermediate-python-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) with for loop

```
l = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
res = []
for x in l:
    query = f"SELECT COUNT(request) FROM table WHERE request LIKE '{x}' AND DATE BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2'"
    cursor.execute(query)
    res.append(cursor.fetchone()[0])
```